# Trying to parse a DNS zone file with awk and am having an issue matching leading characters with awk

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I'm trying to parse a text file with an awk one liner and:

1. Delete the first line (header)
2. Delete all lines that begin with '(' (open paren)
3. Drop the 4th column

Example data:

```
Name    Type    Data    Timestamp
(same as parent folder) Start of Authority (SOA)    [69671], server1.abc.com., hostmaster.abc.com.  static
(same as parent folder) Name Server (NS)    server2.abc.com.    static
access  Host (A)    192.168.99.190  static
apps    Host (A)    192.168.99.181  static
```

I'm able to do 1 & 3, but my regex must be off for the '(' match:

```
awk -F$'\t' 'NR > 1' | awk '!/^(/' '{print toupper($1),$2,$3}' test.txt > out.txt
```

> awk: cmd. line:1: error: Unmatched ( or (: /^(/

I tried escaping the open parenthesis but that didn't work either. I started pipelining the second `awk` because I thought the `NR` filter was getting in the way, but it's obvious I'm missing something (probably basic).

Comment: There are obvious issues with your script but they're unrelated to the error message you're getting which should have been solved by escaping the paren as you say you tired. So, please show us in your question the code you ran with the escaped open paren and any error messages you got or other indications that it "didn't work" so we can help you debug that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1 && !/^\(/{print toupper($1), $2, $3}' file
ACCESS  Host (A)        192.168.99.190
APPS    Host (A)        192.168.99.181
```

Comment: Ed, you provided the fix before I could respond to your comment. Thank you sir.

Comment: You're welcome. The comment still stands though - if you'd like help debugging the issue you had then just do what it suggests.